# Trying to open a pdf file in a new Tab on Chrome browser - not happening

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have Get Method which I am expecting to open a pdf file in a new browser tab, but its not happening - below is the code

```
public void GetDoc(int id)
{
    string fileInfo = "ID=[" + id + "] ";
    try
    {
        var file = this.DomainLogicUnitOfWork.UploadedDocumentManager.GetById(id);
        fileInfo = "FILENAME=[" + file.FileName + "]";

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = file.FileContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.FileName);
        Response.OutputStream.Write(file.DocumentImage, 0, file.DocumentImage.Length);
        Response.Output.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogHandler.LogError(4617, "Error Downloading Document " + fileInfo, ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

My url is opening correctly: http://localhost:xcxcxcx/Upload/GetDoc?id=1088 and it gives a warning when click on the start of the browser address and one more thing is the Word and other documents are being downloaded fine - means they are working fine but problem is just with PDF files. Any suggestions or ideas - 
thank you all friends.

Comment: Is the FileContentType correct? Also, which version of .Net are you using? There are simpler ways of returning a file than this. Where does Reponse come from?

Comment: File ContentType is coming as application/pdf - is that correct?

Comment: If I add this line - it works correctly - but how can I give the file name when user is downloading the file -if (file.FileContentType.ToLower() != "application/pdf")
                    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.FileName);, Response.AppendHeader is the problem

Comment: enclosing within the double quotes resolved the problem like in this one: Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{file.FileName}\"");

Comment: Never do `throw ex;` where `ex` is a caught exception. You'll lose your stack trace. Instead, just do `throw;`.

Answer (score 0):

enclosing within the double quotes resolved the problem like in this one: `Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{file.FileName}\"");`